# Error installing SonataMediaBundle on Symfony CMF

Tags: symfony-cmf, sonata-media-bundle

I try install SonataMediaBundle with Symfony CMF Sandbox and have this exception after install

```
Catchable fatal error: 
Argument 2 passed to Sonata\CoreBundle\Model\BaseManager::__construct() 
must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, 
instance of Sonata\DoctrinePHPCRAdminBundle\Model\ModelManager given, 
called in cmf-sandbox/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 7986 
and defined in  cmf-sandbox/vendor/sonata-project/core-bundle/Model/BaseManager.php on line 41
```

It seems like version collision, but bundles pack was installed via composer with no conflicts, also I try to install older/newer versions, but no result.

I try phpcr and mongodb, is the same.

composer.json:

```
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.1.*",
    "symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "symfony-cmf/search-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "symfony-cmf/seo-bundle":"1.0.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "1.1.*",
    "jackalope/jackalope-jackrabbit": "1.1.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.3",
    "symfony-cmf/block-bundle": "1.1.*",
    "eko/feedbundle": "1.0.*",
    "lunetics/locale-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "0.21.*",
    "wjzijderveld/check-bundles": "1.0.*",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "1.4.*",

    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.*@dev"
```

config.yml:

```
# cmf configuration
doctrine_phpcr:
    # configure the PHPCR session
    session:
        backend: %phpcr_backend%
        workspace: %phpcr_workspace%
        username: %phpcr_user%
        password: %phpcr_pass%
    # enable the ODM layer
    odm:
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            SonataMediaBundle:
                prefix: Sonata\MediaBundle\PHPCR
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        locales:
            en:
                - de
                - fr


sonata_media:
    default_context: default
    db_driver: doctrine_phpcr #doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            providers:
                - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
                - sonata.media.provider.youtube
                - sonata.media.provider.image
                - sonata.media.provider.file

            formats:
                small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
                big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}

    cdn:
        server:
            path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/

    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
            create:     false
```

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit tricky to get the right versions of the Sonata Bundles, we just released 1.1 and tried to improve things a bit there by making the dependencies a bit more explicit. Can you try again?